# Is there a way to call a function when user explicitly kills the Application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, mobile-application

I have implemented firebase push notification in my App. I am using **registerForRemoteNotifications** / **unregisterForRemoteNotifications** to enable and disable push notification. I have implemented the functionality that when user is logged in and the App is in background state, user will receive push notification and when user log out from the App push notification will not be received (I am calling this function on logout to disable push notification 
**[[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications];**).
But the main issue is that when user explicitly kill the application push notifications remains enabled.
I tried using applicationWillTerminate function but when I explicitly terminate/kill the App, its throwing an error "message from debugger terminated due to signal 9". I know that the applicationWillTerminate function will only get called when an app is currently running in the background and not suspended. Is there a way to check when App moves from suspended to not running state? (i.e, App is minimised then user tapped home button twice and clear the App).

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to run a function when user explicitly kills the app. You can check with Apple Documentation on App Life Cycle-
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html

Comment: Thanks Boudhayan. Any suggestion on how to unregister remote notifications when user explicitly kills the App?

Answer (score 0):

Do you work of unregistering notifications in applicationWillTerminate delegate method

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application;
```

[image: Apple documentation clearly says this method will work for apps which donot support background mode and you have 5 seconds of time to execute your tasks]

Comment: Apple documentation clearly states that this method will work for applications which donot support background mode. So probably you can rely on this delegate method.

Comment: Thanks Bankim. I am already using applicationWillTerminate delegate method but its not working. When I explicitly kill the App, its throwing an error :"message from debugger terminated due to signal 9". and application terminated without calling applicationWillTerminate method.
Do you know any other way to unregister notifications when user explicitly kills the App?